# using TryParse as a bool

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a bool that checks to see if a textbox has a number in it, so I have

```
bool ifParsed = int.TryParse(Txtbox1.Text);
```

I know you are meant to have an out value, but I don't want to assign it to anything, I just want it to give a true or false value to use in an if statement.

Comment: Just give an arb int that you never use

Comment: `TryParse` is the best way I think, although there are some other choices

Comment: good point actually, thanks

Comment: Why not just validate client-side if the check is for numeric input only?

Comment: have added as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use

```
int i;
bool ifParsed = int.TryParse(Txtbox1.Text, out i);
```

and then never use `i`

Comment: +1. Or you can even wrap it into an extension method to remove need for declaring local `int`.

Comment: @user3000043 Glad I could help. Accept it if you dont mind :)

Comment: sorry had to wait, then I forgot :L

Answer (score 3):

You could easily add an extension method such as:

```
public static bool IsInteger(this string value)
{
   int i;
   return int.TryParse(value, out i);
}
```

And then use like:

```
if (Txtbox1.Text.IsInteger())
{
   // DO stuff.
}
```

Your extension method will need to be declared in a static class also.